# MySql table Create and Drop slowness in MySql

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a slow query log saying:

> creation and dropping of the table taking more than 1 hour which was
>   expected to be completed in 5 to 7 minutes.

**LOGFILE**:

```
# Time: 171120 11:40:55
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 35649
# Query_time: 6603.897055  Lock_time: 0.006114 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 5313105728
SET timestamp=1511178055;
CREATE table `table_1` as  SELECT id FROM  table_2;

# Time: 171120 11:40:56
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id: 34286
# Query_time: 6312.637681  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1511178056;
drop table if exists `table_1`;
```

Details

```
MySQL Version: 5.6
Mysql engine: InnoDB
Total Tables : 760 + temp tables(create/drop)
Total Size : 70GB
RAM : 64 GB
InnoDB buffer pool size: 40G
```

**Question:**

any suggestions to debug the issue?

Comment: `CREATE table `table_1 as  SELECT id FROM  table_2;`   creates a temporary table in memory.. if the table in memory becomes to big it will be convert into a MyISAM diskbased temporary table. 5313105728 * 4 bytes = 21.2524229 gigabytes.. Do you really expect this data will be copyed in a few seconds?

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland, it use to take 300 to 400 seconds before and we never getting this in MySQL slow log with more than 400 seconds.

Comment: 300 to 400 seconds is not a few seconds. 10 second or less is a few seconds...You sure the server didn't need to handle more intensive read/write operations to the same time.

Comment: sorry, it was around 5 to 7 minutes. These temp tables used for report regeneration and which will create based on report generation request from the user. May or may not be read/write operation same time because which is based on users.

Comment: Can we get read/write operations happening or not details from MySQL log?

Comment: If you use Percona Server, you can enable innodb read/write operations in their enhanced slow query log. See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/diagnostics/slow_extended.html for `log_slow_verbosity` option. If you don't use Percona Server, then perhaps the [sys schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html) can help.

Comment: What was the setting of `innodb_file_per_table`?  What was the filesystem -- ZFS, XFS, EXT4, etc?

Comment: @RickJames, innodb_file_per_table is ON and file system is EXT4.

Comment: @BillKarwin, we are not using Percona Server.

Comment: But was _that_ table built with file_per_table?  I don't know if EXT4 is a fs that is terribly slow at deleting a file (which is what `DROP TABLE` with file_per_table on would be doing.)

Comment: I'm inclined to say that your storage layer is just way too busy with writes, or perhaps your whole system is swapping. Check with `iostat` and `vmstat`.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. They really want questions about coding, and this sounds like a question about operations. I'm voting to move it to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok @BillKarwin, I will check iostat and vmstat during the query execution.